# Можно ли программным путем запустить Регламентное задание?

Tags: 1с

На кнопку "Провести" в моей документе нужно добавить обработчик события, который запускает Регламентное задание. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
Отб = Новый Структура;
    ИмяРЗ = "Дополнительная обработка: ПроверкаВыполненияОбмена / Команда: ПроверкаВыполненияОбмена";
    Отб.Вставить("Наименование", ИмяРЗ); 
    Задания = РегламентныеЗадания.ПолучитьРегламентныеЗадания(Отб);
    Если Задания.Количество()>0 тогда
        Задание = Задания[0];
    Иначе
        Задание = РегламентныеЗадания.СоздатьРегламентноеЗадание("ЗапускДополнительныхОбработок");
    КонецЕсли;
    Задание.Использование = Истина;
    Задание.Наименование =   ИмяРЗ;
    Расписание = Новый РасписаниеРегламентногоЗадания;
    Расписание.ПериодНедель = 1;
    МД = Новый Массив();
    МД.Добавить(1);
    МД.Добавить(2);
    МД.Добавить(3);
    МД.Добавить(4);
    МД.Добавить(5);
    МД.Добавить(6);
    МД.Добавить(7);
    Расписание.ДниНедели = МД;
    Расписание.ДатаНачала = ТекущаяДата();
    Расписание.ПериодПовтораВТечениеДня = 1800;
    Расписание.ПериодПовтораДней = 1;
    Задание.Расписание = Расписание;
    ПарЗад = Новый Массив;
    ПарЗад.Добавить(Справочники.ДополнительныеОтчетыИОбработки.НайтиПоНаименованию("ПроверкаВыполненияОбмена"));
    ПарЗад.Добавить("ПроверкаВыполненияОбмена");
    Задание.Параметры = ПарЗад;
    Задание.Записать();
```